# Java recursive function below what is the problem?

Tags: java, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

```
    public static int score(int[][] array, int win, int turn) {
        int score = 0;
        if (GamePrinciples.gameEnd(array, win)) {
            if (GamePrinciples.draw(array)) {
                score = 0;
            } else if (GamePrinciples.winningBoard(array, win)[0] == 1) {
                score = 1;
            } else {
                score = -1;
            }
        } else {
            for (int[][] i : children(array, win, turn)) {
                score += score(i, win, GamePrinciples.nextPlayer(turn));
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

briefly this program is part of my minimax algorithm. So the problem is that I get a stack over flow. Where am I going wrong?
if an array is in ending mode then if it is a draw it gives a score of zero if player one wins then a score of one and if player two wins it gives a score of two.
if the array is however not in the ending state we get the children of the array (immediate children that is the boards that result from the current board with only one move). The score of the board will be the sum of the score of each of its children. The logic seems okay and the other methods such as children, nextPlayer, winningBoard, draw all work fine with testing. So I am guessing there is problem with this kind of recursive implementation. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: How many times is this function called? Assuming your gameEnd method works as intended, it could be that the function is called way too many times either way, which can fill up the stack.

Comment: I give array = [ [ 2,1,1 ], [ 0,2,2 ], [ 1,0,1 ] ]  and win = 3 and turn = 2 as the input. win =3 means that there should be 3 items in a row for the game to end. turn 2 means its the second player turn (which by looking at the numbers theres 4 1s and 3 2s). Because there is only 2 empty spots the score method in only called *3* times. (because one of the situations the board has a winning state). So do you think that my current implementation is correct and there might be a fault in my other methods?

Comment: The thing to do is to instrument the code.  E.g. display the board on every entry into score().  ie., debugging is called for.

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The problem might be in the `children` method, which you haven't shown.  What is that method supposed to do?

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems wrong in the loop:

```
for (int[][] i : children(array, win, turn)) {
```

I haven’t tested, but you should call the method *children()* outside the *for*.
By calling the method within the *for* clause, you are always returning the initial array instead of iterating through it.

So try putting the *children()* method return to a variable and iterate through this variable.

Something like:

```
… c = children(…)
for(int[][] i : c) {
…
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but still get stackoverflow. Thanks though

Comment: This will make no difference at all.  The only part of an extended for loop that's repeated is the part between the `{ }` characters.